# Prefilling a <Create> record with render <Button/> cause the application to crash (react-admin)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

Good morning. I'm using react-admin (2.9.4) and faced with problem: 
I try to prefill a **Create** record and display Create component with custom **toolbar**, but if I use [location.search](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#prefilling-a-create-record) for this I got my app crash.

I use the same construction like in an example

```
....
component={Link}
to={{
  pathname: '/comments/create',
  search: '?id=' + record.id,
}}
....
```

My create component looks like:

```
const ToolBar = (props) => (
  <Toolbar {...props}>
    <SaveButton />
    <Button />
  </Toolbar>
)


const MyCreate = props => (
  <Create {...props}>
    <SimpleForm toolbar={<ToolBar/>}>
      <TextInput source="title" />
      <TextInput source="summary" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Create>
);
```

In this combination I get **Something went wrong** and warnings mostly about not recognisable props, e.g. **basePath**.

```
index.js:1437 Warning: React does not recognize the `basePath` prop on a DOM element.
```

If I comment out **Button** in tooltip it works fine.
I would be grateful if someone tell me what could be the problem, and how the **location.search** affects the render of the **Button**.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Prefilling a  Record" 
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html

The Create form tries to get the initial parameters in the given format:

```
const CreateRelatedCommentButton = ({ record }) => (
    <Button
        component={Link}
        to={{
            pathname: '/comments/create',
            state: { record: { post_id: record.id } },
        }}
    >
        Write a comment for that post
    </Button>
);
```

If you want to use your search line to transfer parameters, You can try this:

```
import { stringify } from 'query-string'

let search = stringify({
  myparams: JSON.stringify(
    {
      id: record.id, 
    })
})
```

To remove this warning you need to implement your button component:

```
// ToolbarButton.js

import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import classnames from 'classnames'
import { Button } from 'react-admin'
import { withStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core'

const styles = createStyles({
  button: {
    marginTop: '0em', 
  },
  iconPaddingStyle: {
    marginRight: '0.5em',
  },
})

const sanitizeRestProps = ({
  basePath,
  invalid,
  pristine,
  record,
  saving,
  submitOnEnter,
  handleSubmit,
  handleSubmitWithRedirect,
  ...rest
}) => rest

const ToolbarButton = ({ className, classes = {}, icon, ...rest }) => (
  <Button
    size="large"
    className={classnames(classes.button, className)}
    {...sanitizeRestProps(rest)}
  >
    { icon ? React.cloneElement(icon, { className: classes.iconPaddingStyle }) : null }
  </Button>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, I don't need to make transfer parameters, because react-admin takes **id** from parameters and uses it like field of record. So, when I redirect to **Create** I get record with my id, then I just fill in the remaining fields and save object with my id. But, in this case, I get error if in toolbar use Button (I mentioned this in a question)

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. But, could you please clarify this moment. Why if we use **locations.search** Button works only after **sanitizeProps**?

Comment: As I understand it, the value from locations.search ends up in the attribute of the underlying HTML element, which causes: "TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value"

Comment: Interesting, is this issue or not. Thanks again.